# Can I install application directly in a VDA and use it in catalog (Xenapp essentials)

Tags: azure, citrix, xenapp

Can I install any applicAtions in VDA in xenapp essentials and use it in the catalog, I am talking about defining a catalog and using the same catalog in azure to install any applications, would that applications reflect in the catalog?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended approach. It is always better to update your master image with the application and then update the catalog with new master image.

Here is a video that walks you through catalog image update workflow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAMOoYLhMTw